# Feign not encoding param

Tags: java, encoding, parameters, jackson, feign

I'm refactoring a legacy codebase to use Feign and I have some problems:

1. No one Feign log statements are printed to console

   - Despite instantiating with a logger and full log level
2. Feign is not encoding my reservationSearch parameter

   - Feign just `POST` the `toString` of the `Object`

Feign definition:

```
public interface EPCReservationClient {
    @RequestLine("POST v1/searchReservations")
    @Headers({"clientId: {clientId}", "Content-Type: application/json", 
              "Authentication: {authentication}"})
    @Body("{reservationSearch}")
    ReservationSearchResponse reservationSearch(
        @Param("authentication") String authentication, //apiToken
        @Param("clientId") String clientId,
        @Param("reservationSearch") 
        ReservationSearch<ReservationSearchParameters> reservationSearch);
}
```

Feign instantiation

```
Feign.builder()
    .logger(new Logger.JavaLogger())
    .decoder(new JacksonDecoder())
    .encoder(new JacksonEncoder(new ObjectMapper().findAndRegisterModules()))
    .logLevel(Logger.Level.FULL)
    .target(EPCReservationClient.class, restUrl);
```

Param type (don't kill me, not my code):

```
public class ReservationSearch<T> {

    @JsonProperty("hotelID")
    private final int hotelID;
    private final String languageId;
    @JsonProperty("reservationSearchParameters")
    private final T parameters;
    @JsonProperty("reservationID")
    private final List<Long> reservationID;

    public ReservationSearch(int hotelID, T parameters, final List<Long> reservationID) {
        this.hotelID = hotelID;
        this.languageId = "1033";
        this.parameters = parameters;
        this.reservationID = Optional.ofNullable(reservationID)
                                     .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList);
    }

    public static ReservationSearch<ReservationSearchParameters> forLastName(
        int maxRecords, int hotelId, String lastName) {
        return new ReservationSearch<>(hotelId, new ReservationSearchParameters(maxRecords, lastName, null), null);
    }

    public static ReservationSearch<ReservationSearchParameters> forConfirmationNumber(
        int maxRecords, int hotelId, String number) {
        return new ReservationSearch<>(hotelId, new ReservationSearchParameters(maxRecords, null, number), null);
    }

    public static ReservationSearch<ReservationSearchParameters> forReservationId(
            final int maxRecords,
            final int hotelId,
            final String reservationNumber) {
        ReservationSearch<ReservationSearchParameters> reservationSearchParametersReservationSearch = new ReservationSearch<>(
                hotelId,
                new ReservationSearchParameters(
                        maxRecords,
                        null,
                        null),
                Collections.singletonList(Long.valueOf(reservationNumber)));
        return reservationSearchParametersReservationSearch;
    }

    public int getHotelID() {
        return hotelID;
    }

    public String getLanguageId() {
        return languageId;
    }

    public T getParameters() {
        return parameters;
    }

    public List<Long> getReservationID() {
        return reservationID;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        final ReservationSearch that = (ReservationSearch) o;

        return new EqualsBuilder()
            .append(hotelID, that.hotelID)
            .append(languageId, that.languageId)
            .append(parameters, that.parameters)
            .append(reservationID, that.reservationID)
            .isEquals();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 37)
            .append(hotelID)
            .append(languageId)
            .append(parameters)
            .append(reservationID)
            .toHashCode();
    }

}
```

ReservationSearchParameters :

```
public class ReservationSearchParameters {
    private final String travelerLastName;
    private final String confirmationNumber;
    private final int maxRecordsLimit;

    public ReservationSearchParameters(int maxRecordsLimit, String travelerLastName, String confirmationNumber) {
        this.maxRecordsLimit = maxRecordsLimit;
        this.travelerLastName = travelerLastName;
        this.confirmationNumber = confirmationNumber;
    }

    public String getTravelerLastName() { return travelerLastName; }

    public String getConfirmationNumber() { return confirmationNumber; }

    public int getMaxRecordsLimit() { return maxRecordsLimit; }

}
```

Comment: It's a parameter, not a request body. You'll need to expand it yourself if you want anything more than `toString()`.

Comment: @chrylis I thought that, given that I'm using the JacksonEncoder it would be encoded behind the scenes. Is there no way to do it automagically without having to use an expander?

Comment: Well, *how* exactly for a query parameter? Convert to JSON and URL-encode that? Kinda odd. Unpack the fields and treat it as a flat-map? Potential conflicts, non-obvious. These aren't problems for a *body*, but for a *parameter*, there's no sane default. You'll have to explain it to Feign yourself.

Comment: @chrylis I think what I really want to do is remove the @Body("{reservationSearch}") and @Param("reservationSearch") annotations from the above code. That should trigger JacksonEncoder.

Comment: I will note that from an API-design perspective, it's unusual to send search parameters as something besides query parameters. It's certainly not *forbidden*, but it's atypical.

Comment: @chrylis Agreed, unfortunately I have no control over the destination API, and it's designed to accept the reservationSearch object as the POST body... In any case, thanks to you I was able to figure out what I was doing wrong, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header (`@Headers` and `@HeaderMap`) and body template (`@Body`) params are always considered pre-encoded. Only query params (`@QueryMap` and `@Param`s that reference a query parameter) will be URL encoded.

If you want your body object to be encoded via the `Encoder`, then don't supply any `@Body` template, and don't annotate your body parameter with `@Param` (that is only intended to be used for template parameters). The un-annotated body parameter will then be fed to the `Encoder` specified in your `Feign.builder().encoder(new FooEncoder())` line.